# Dock acting wonky on mouse-over, showing on lock screen, etc

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, lock-screen, ubuntu-dock, dock

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS running GNOME 3.28.2 about a month ago and have intermittently had the following problem.

1. Some time after the system has been running (never upon startup), when I mouse over the dock, the icons move farther apart. When I mouse off, the icons move back to their normal positions.
2. About when this behavior is happening, when the screen is locked, the dock appears (non-functional) on top of the lock screen.
3. I try solving this by executing `DISPLAY=:0 gnome-shell --replace`. Usually this works, but it didn't most recently; in fact, the screen completely froze up and I had to reboot.

I tried replacing the nouveau driver with the proper NVIDIA driver last night, with no issues, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: This bug was [reported][1] as being fixed in the package gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock, 0.9.1ubuntu18.04.3. Perhaps the bug will go away if you update to that package.


  [1]: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1769383